Error while generating schema using AWS Glue Cralwer, using escape characters for ':'
I have stored the Amazon Connect agent records and CTR records in same data stream and using firehose loaded into an S3 where I am finding issues to read the data using Athena, I used AWS Glue Crawler to generate a schema. The issue is at:
The data generated has the following attributes:
"SegmentAttributes": {
        "connect:Subtype": {
            "ValueString": "connect:Telephony"
        }
    },
    "SystemEndpoint": {
        "Address": "+1xxxxxxxxxx",
        "Type": "TELEPHONE_NUMBER"
    },
    "Tags": {
        "aws:connect:instanceId": "0xxxxxaavv-78xxxxxb569",
        "aws:connect:systemEndpoint": "+1xxxxxxxxxx"
    },

The crawler has generated the schema and for this block it looks like:
{
    "Name": "segmentattributes",
    "Type": "struct<connect\\:Subtype:struct<ValueString:string>>"
  },
  {
    "Name": "systemendpoint",
    "Type": "struct<Address:string,Type:string>"
  },
  {
    "Name": "tags",
    "Type": "struct<aws\\:connect\\:instanceId:string,aws\\:connect\\:systemEndpoint:string>"
  },

While I run the table I get this error:
HIVE_INVALID_METADATA: Glue table 'ktxxxxxxgxxt.coxxxxxv_bnbn' column 'segmentattributes' has invalid data type: struct<connect\:Subtype:struct<ValueString:string>>

How to solve this issue?

That is expected behaviour because it doesn't support any other alphanumeric characters except _ and . in the column names. Hence it will require custom DDL statement and the key mapping to the actual column name using WITH SERDEPROPERTIES in DDL.
With mapping property, you can map the fields to Hive-compatible name.
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE aws_connect_tbl (
    SegmentAttributes:struct<connect_subtype:struct<ValueString:string>>,
    SystemEndpoint:struct<Address:string,Type:string>,
    Tags:struct<aws_connect_instanceId:string,aws_connect_systemEndpoint:string>,
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    "mapping.connect_subtype"="connect:Subtype",
    "mapping.aws_connect_instanceId"="aws:connect:instanceId",
    "mapping.aws_connect_systemEndpoint"="aws:connect:systemEndpoint"
    )
LOCATION 's3://bucketname/<s3objectpath>'

